# Clutter 1.6. is slows down screen rendering for first time alone

Tags: clutter

We were using clutter to render the screen and process the GUI events on IMX31 board.

The problem description :-

```
    On startup the buttons,texture will be loaded into memory. When we click any buttons then associated panel(ClutterGroup) will be processed and shown in Clutter main stage.
```

The screen rendering is slow for the first time when it processes all the child and making it visible. it also throws 230 redraw error messages in clutter-stage.c for the first time.
The screen rendering time crosses 2 seconds.

```
Clutter-Message: [PAINT] ./clutter-stage.c:3369: First redraw request
Clutter-Message: [PAINT] ./clutter-stage.c:3380: Redraw request number 1
Clutter-Message: [PAINT] ./clutter-stage.c:3380: Redraw request number 2
Clutter-Message: [TEXTURE] ./clutter-texture.c:311: Texture realized
Clutter-Message: [TEXTURE] ./clutter-texture.c:311: Texture realized
Clutter-Message: [TEXTURE] ./clutter-texture.c:311: Texture realized
Clutter-Message: [TEXTURE] ./clutter-texture.c:311: Texture realized
Clutter-Message: [TEXTURE] ./clutter-texture.c:311: Texture realized
Clutter-Message: [TEXTURE] ./clutter-texture.c:311: Texture realized
Clutter-Message: [TEXTURE] ./clutter-texture.c:311: Texture realized
Clutter-Message: [TEXTURE] ./clutter-texture.c:311: Texture realized
Clutter-Message: [TEXTURE] ./clutter-texture.c:311: Texture realized
Clutter-Message: [TEXTURE] ./clutter-texture.c:311: Texture realized
Clutter-Message: [TEXTURE] ./clutter-texture.c:311: Texture realized
Clutter-Message: [TEXTURE] ./clutter-texture.c:311: Texture realized
Clutter-Message: [TEXTURE] ./clutter-texture.c:311: Texture realized
Clutter-Message: [TEXTURE] ./clutter-texture.c:311: Texture realized
Clutter-Message: [TEXTURE] ./clutter-texture.c:311: Texture realized
Clutter-Message: [TEXTURE] ./clutter-texture.c:311: Texture realized
Clutter-Message: [TEXTURE] ./clutter-texture.c:311: Texture realized
Clutter-Message: [PAINT] ./clutter-stage.c:3380: Redraw request number 3
Clutter-Message: [PAINT] ./clutter-stage.c:3380: Redraw request number 4
Clutter-Message: [PAINT] ./clutter-stage.c:3380: Redraw request number 5
Clutter-Message: [PAINT] ./clutter-stage.c:3380: Redraw request number 6
Clutter-Message: [PAINT] ./clutter-stage.c:3380: Redraw request number 7
Clutter-Message: [PAINT] ./clutter-stage.c:3380: Redraw request number 8
Clutter-Message: [PAINT] ./clutter-stage.c:3380: Redraw request number 9

                               .....................
```

When we go into the same screen again the screen transition is so fast and it is in microseconds.

Also there will not be more redraw messages and only 19 redraw messages.

Just i want to know how can we avoid Redraw request in clutter-stage.c (Clutter 1.6)?.
Which clutter function calls triggers Redraw request?.

Thanks in advance,

With Regards,
Karthick

Answer (score 0):

first of all, Clutter 1.6 is the old stable version, so you may want to check Clutter 1.8.

your slow-down on the initial frame is probably due to uploading the image data to the GPU: this operation is sensitive, and depends on the amount of memory bandwidth you have at your disposal.

my suggestion is to try and not load all textures synchronously at start up, but to load each texture individually and lazily, one at a time.